# mysql split row to multiple columns and rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure and these values in column assoc.

```
| id | assoc |

| 1 | |3|-1|107|-4|146|-6| |

| 2 | |19|-3|107|-5| |

| 3 | |42|-1| |
```

You can see it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf15d)

This is a wrong mysql table structure. So I think that the right structure it must be:

```
| id | assoc | attrib | order |

| 1  | 3 | 1 | 1 |

| 1  | 107 | 4 | 2 |

| 1  | 146 | 6 | 3 |

| 2  | 19 | 3 | 1 |

| 2  | 107 | 5 | 2 |

| 3  | 42 | 1 | 1 |
```

Is possible to do with a mysql script on phpmyadmin?

Comment: _“How it can be converted?”_ – for example by a _script_ that you write for that purpose …

Comment: Do you know the script which can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @prev := null;

SET @cnt := 0;

SELECT id,blah,mah,IF(@prev <> id, @cnt := 1, @cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rank, @prev := id 
FROM(
SELECT id,REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(assoc,'|',2),'|','')*1 as blah, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(assoc,'-0'),'|',3),'-',-1)as mah FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT id,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(assoc,'|0'),'|',4),'|',-1)*1 as blah,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(assoc,'-0'),'|',5),'-',-1)as mah FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT id,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(assoc,'|0'),'|',6),'|',-1)*1 as blah,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(assoc,'-0'),'|',7),'-',-1)as mah FROM table1
)x
WHERE   x.mah !='0'
ORDER BY x.id ,x.blah
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf15d/60)

Comment: @user3450939 it would be nice if you accepted the answer(click under the score arrows)